# What are the restrictions on the Hamiltonian in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian

In quantum mechanics, we usually write the Hamiltonian as:

$$\hat{H}=\hat{T}+\hat{V}$$

But in classical mechanics, there are several reasons why it **would not have this form**:

- We've chosen some particular coordinate system where there is no conservation of energy (we're neglecting the source of external forces).
- We can modify the Hamiltonian without changing the equations of motion:

  The Lagrangian can be written as: $L=\frac{1}{3}T^2+2TV-V^2$. The Hamiltonian would be:

  $\hat{H}=p\left[\frac{\left(\sqrt{9p^2m^8 +32m^9V^3}+3pm^4\right)^{1/3}}{\sqrt[3]{2}m^2}-\frac{2\sqrt[3]{2}mV}{\left(\sqrt{9p^2m^8 +32m^9V^3}+3pm^4\right)}\right]-L=(T+V)^2$

  The eigenvalues of this operator are $E^2$, not the energy.

**Do we consider this possibilities in quantum mechanics?** In the negative case, why do we discard them?

And (besides the necessity to be self-adjoint and bounded from below) does the Hamiltonian have some restriction on the operators it includes (position, angular momentum,...)?

Comment: Self-adjointness guarantees a unitary time evolution and boundedness from below stability. I think that this is sufficient for an acceptable Hamitonian. The decomposition H=T+V, although quite often the case, does not seem to be necessary. In addition, to have a proper Lagrangian (from which the Hamiltonian is derived, a convexity property is required.

Comment: @Urgje Is convexity relavant here, since this Hamiltonian is not derived from the Lagrangian? I know that in QM there are Lagrangian, but are there Legendre trasforms?

Comment: I am not an expert on this matter so let me refer to   http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103997/
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/482553/

Comment: Just a side remark, there is less restriction of Hamiltonian in non-relativistic quantum mechanics (Hermitian, bounded from below). It is much restricted in QFT by gauge invariance and Lorentz symmetry in the Lagrangian.

Comment: You end up with ambiguities from the expression $(T+V)^2$ for, e.g., the simple harmonic oscillator. This is because we cannot consistently quantize terms involving higher than quadratic powers, and the cross terms would be a nightmare to deal with adequately...

Answer (score 2):

**Myth 1: We Need Unitary Time Evolution.**

*Problem a: Self-Adjointness.* This would require the Hamiltonian to be self-adjoint. But there are interesting situations when this won't be true, consider the following papers:

1. F. Bagarello, A. Inoue, C. Trapani, "Non-self-adjoint hamiltonians defined by Riesz bases". Eprint [arXiv:1402.6199](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6199)
2. Fabio Bagarello, Miloslav Znojil, "The dynamical problem for a non self-adjoint Hamiltonian". *Operator Theory: Advances and Applications* **221** (2012) 109--119, [arXiv:1105.4716](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4716)

*Problem b: Constrained Systems.* For topological field theory, parametrized fields, or even the relativistic particle (taking the action to be its proper time), the Hamiltonian operator no longer controls time-evolution.

The Hamiltonian instead becomes a *constraint* for these systems. It *vanishes* when acting on the physical states. Asking the time evolution operator to be "unitary" is meaningless for physical states.

For more on constrained systems, see, e.g.,

1. Henneaux and Teitelboim's *Quantization of Gauge Systems*
2. Andreas W. Wipf, "Hamilton's Formalism for Systems with Constraints". Eprint [arXiv:hep-th/9312078](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9312078)

**Myth 2: We Can Quantize Anything.**

Not quite true. For example, as I noted in my comment, if we consider the simple harmonic oscillator (dropping constants for simplicity)
$$ T = v^{2},\quad\mbox{and}\quad V=x^{2}$$
then
$$ H = (p^{2}+x^{2})^{2}. $$
But look, when we try to quantize this, we can't put hats on everything and hope it all works for the best. Why? Well, how do we quantize $x^{2}p^{2}$? Observe
$$ (\hat{x}\hat{p})^{2}\neq \hat{x}^{2}\hat{p}^{2}\neq\left(\frac{\hat{p}\hat{x}+\hat{x}\hat{p}}{2}\right)^{2}$$
They give inequivalent commutators.

This ambiguity is well-known in the literature. See, for example:

1. S. Twareque Ali, Miroslav Engliš, "Quantization Methods: A Guide for Physicists and Analysts". *Rev.Math.Phys.* **17** (2005) 391-490, [arXiv:math-ph/0405065](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0405065)

**So...what DO we do?**

"We do what works" is the motto! It'd be nice to have some algorithm that *always works no matter what*...but instead we restrict our focus to the *physically relevant* situations.

And even then, we only use the quantized systems that *make sense*.

In a sense, this is the *proper* route: instead of asking for a procedure to turn something classical into something quantum, we should think that nature *already is* quantized and we need to seek out the quantum model that *emulates* the natural phenomena we're interested in.