# Changing sign of Lagrangian & Hamiltonian: how to interpret energies then?

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, conventions

In Lagrangian mechanics, it is possible to multiply the Lagrangian by a constant $a$. Let's assume I take $a=-1$.

Then, the Hamiltonian will have its sign changed as well. And it will represent the good dynamic as well.

What I don't understand is the possible energy interpretation we can have of the Hamiltonian. If $H$ and $-H$ are physically equivalent, how to know what is the lowest energy of a system?

How to make connection with statistical mechanics for example (canonical probabilities).

[edit]

Let's say everything is classical, consider for example a classical Ising Hamiltonian: $H=J S_1 S_2$ with $J>0$. In one description the fundamental would be $++$ or $--$, in the other, $+-$ or $-+$. The physical description are thus different in term of statistical physics.

[edit2]

I think that @knzhou is indeed the good one but something is still perturbing me. If someone gives you those two equivalent hamiltonian: $H=J S_1 S_2$ and $H'=-J S_1 S_2$

You want to know what is the occupied state at $0K$. Conceptually would you agree it is absolutely impossible to know what it will be, you could state ($++$,$--$), or ($+-$ or $-+$) because the formalism is symmetric via $H \rightarrow -H$.

Then to know what in practice you will see you **must** do an experiment. This experiment will tell you which sign to choose so that it matches statistical physics description. It is impossible to know theoretically what it will be.

If no experiment are needed it necesserally mean that I need an **extra** mathematical axiom in addition to hamiltonian formalism to do this mapping. If so, which one ?

Comment: Related: [Are the Hamiltonian and Lagrangian always convex functions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103997/2451)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that L' = -L then indeed one can see that H' = -H, but L' doesn't longer equals to T - V but to -T + V which is T' - V'. So you can see that although you get the same dynamical solutions your representation of the question is different and in this representation H' = E' = T' + V' = -(T + V) = -E = -H.

So in other words H' is just another representation of the same problem with the same solutions, we don't care that the energy is not the same because we care only about the difference in the energy which is the same (zero in this case).

Note that we assumed that H = T + V, which is not trivial as one sometimes think. (See discussion in Goldstein 339).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that we will have the same dynamic. What confuses me is related to quantum mechanic but is probably more general. If $H$ and $-H$ are physically totally equivalent, then after quantizing the theory I would have a problem to find the fundamental in energy for example. For example it could give me $\hbar \omega a^{\dagger} a$ and $-\hbar \omega a^{\dagger} a$ as two possible hamiltonian for a harmonic oscillator which is weird. In term of statistical physics I would end up in a paradox with the second description: what would be the fundamental in energy ?

Comment: I actually gave a more simple example with classical ising hamiltonian in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your weird definition the *schmenergy* $\tilde{E} = -E$. Everything about physics works the same, as long as you are consistent with flipping the signs everywhere.

- The temperature of an object is defined by $T = dE/dS$. Note that $\tilde{E}$ appears nowhere in this definition.
- If you want an alternative definition that involves $\tilde{E}$, you could define the *schemperature* $\tilde{T} = d \tilde{E} / dS$. Then you could have a whole theory of *schmermodynamics* based on $\tilde{T}$.
- The crucial point is that you need to focus on unambiguous physical predictions, and not those tied to your weird choice of words. For example, is it "paradoxical" that normal objects will have negative schemperatures? No, because schemperature is a different thing from temperature, so we shouldn't expect it to have the same intuitive properties.
- As an example of an unambiguous physical statement, you can carry on your derivations in *schmermodynamics*, in exactly the same way as a standard textbook but with extra minus signs, to show that as the *schemperature* approaches zero, the *schmenergy* approaches a *maximum*. But this is exactly the same thing as the energy approaching a minimum, so your results aren't any different from the standard ones.

More generally, our intuition for energy applies to quantities that are of the form 
$$E = mv^2/2 + \text{other stuff}.$$
You are free to define an alternative quantity of the form 
$$\tilde{E} = -mv^2/2 + \text{other stuff},$$
there's nothing mathematically illegal about it. It just won't obey the same intuition. I mean, you are also free to call the number $2$ "three", but then you shouldn't be surprised by the fact that $\text{"three"} + \text{"three"} = 4$.

Comment: Well actually I am not totally convinced even if I think that indeed it is a matter a convention. Let's say two person give you two different hamiltonian: $H=J S_1 S_2$ and the other $H'=-J S_1 S_2$ at this point, how do you know what would be the fundamental in energy which is something you can measure experimentally and is physically well defined. As the hamiltonian formalism is totally symmetric for me there is something missing in the description, some extra information.

Comment: Would you say that you must have experimentally access to measurements. Like you see experimentally that the fundamental is up-up / down down to then know that  what we usually call energy is associated to $H'$ ? Said differently without mapping to any experiment it is conceptually not possible to know what would be the fundamental in energy as the hamiltonian description respects the symetry $H \rightarrow -H $ ?

Comment: I added an edit that formalize in a similar way my two comments.

Comment: @StarBucK Sorry, but I'm not seeing how your further question is any different. Yes, if somebody gave you something with units of energy, but didn't tell you if it were energy or schmenergy, then you would have to do an experiment to find out. It's just as if I told you that I had "umptergargle" books on my shelf, but I didn't tell you what my made-up word "umptergargle" meant, in terms of the familiar number words ("one", "two") you already know. Well, then to figure out how many books are on the shelf, you would have to go count. What is paradoxical about this?

Comment: @StarBucK To restate what I said in the answer: if your system is _isolated_, it doesn't matter whether it's energy or schmenergy, because for an isolated system, both energy and schmenergy are conserved; the dynamics are identical. If you want to talk about what the system acts like in _thermal equilibrium_ then you necessarily have to couple it to a bath. As long as we've fixed the convention for defining $H_{\text{bath}}$, then this also fixes the convention for defining $H_{\text{sys}}$. You are right there's an arbitrary sign, but you only get to choose it _once_ in all of physics.