# How are conjugate variables in mechanics and stat mech related to duality in convex optimization?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, optimization

I recently studied duality in optimization where a primal optimization problem can be casted as a dual problem which provides meaningful lower bounds on the primal. There is also a notion of conjugate variables in mechanics (velocity/momentum) and thermodynamics (energy/temperature or pressure/volume for example) via the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation). Are these two related, if so how?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103997/2451