# How causality and unitarity are ensured given a non-linear electromagnetic Lagrangian?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, causality, unitarity, non-linear-systems

I am reading [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.12118) on non-linear electrodynamics (NED). On page 8, below equation (5.1) the author states that the modified electromagnetism parameter $\gamma$ should be non-negative in order to ensure causality and unitarity. How can we see that?
For completeness, here's the Lagrangian

$$L_{ModMax} = -\frac{\cosh \gamma}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \frac{\sinh \gamma}{4}\sqrt{(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})^2 + (F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu})^2} \tag{5.1}$$

Comment: On page 5 the author is referring to some of his sources, did you have a look there? "Other restrictions on the form of the NED action are imposed by the physical requirements of
causality and unitarity of the theory (see e.g. [35–39])."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very next sentence below eq. (5.1) Ref. 1 writes:

> These values of $\gamma$ also ensure that the Lagrangian density is a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of the electric field $E^i$.

And on p. 5:

> Other restrictions on the form of the NED action are imposed by the physical requirements of causality and unitarity of the theory (see e.g. [35–39]). These are related to the requirement that the Lagrangian density is a convex function of the electric field strength $E^i$, i.e. that the Hessian $3 \times 3$ matrix
> $${\cal L}_{ij} ~=~\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}}{\partial E^i\partial E^j} \tag{3.6}$$
> has only non-negative eigenvalues for all values of ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf B}$.

This is because the electric field $E^i$ is the momentum field to the gauge field $A_i$, so that the Hessian is the kinetic term. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103997/2451) related Phys.SE post.

On one hand, for $\gamma\geq 0$ the Lagrangian density (5.1) is a non-negative linear combination of convex functions and therefore also convex.

On the other hand, to actually check that the Lagrangian density (5.1) is *not* a convex function for $\gamma<0$, calculate  e.g. $$ \left. {\cal L}_{xx}\right|_{{\bf E}=(0,1+\epsilon,0),{\bf B}=(1,0,0)} \quad\sim\quad
\frac{\sinh\gamma}{|\epsilon|}
\quad\text{for}\quad \epsilon~\to~ 0,$$
and note that it would be negative.

References:

1. D.P. Sorokin, *Introductory Notes on Non-linear Electrodynamics and its Applications,* [arXiv:2112.12118](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.12118).

Comment: Thanks for explaining that part with the Hessian!!!